# Replace after a specific pattern

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, find

Suppose I have a string as follows:

```
RESULT=100
```

How would I replace everything following 'RESULT=' so that the string reads:

```
RESULT=200
```

The closest I've gotten so far is to use:

```
:%s/\(RESULT=.*\)\@<=/200/g
```

But this simply places the desired string after the existing one:

```
RESULT=100200
```

Can anyone help me?

Kindest regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is by using [`\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) to set the "start" of the match, so that everything before `\zs` is untouched by the replacement:

```
:%s/RESULT=\zs.*/200/g
```

Your original attempt using a lookbehind was also on the right track: you just put the `.*` part in the wrong place:

```
:%s/\(RESULT=\)\@<=.*/200/g
```

This replaces *anything* that comes after a `RESULT=`, whereas your search replaced *nothing* that comes after a `RESULT=.*`.

However, `\zs` and `\ze` are recommended over lookarounds when it's possible to use them, because lookarounds can be slow.

As [@DJMcMayhem notes in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/replace-after-a-specific-pattern/21291#comment38330_21291), yet another approach is to allow the substitution command to replace the `RESULT=` part, but include that text in the replacement by using a capture group:

```
:%s/\(RESULT=\).*/\1200
```

Comment: Perfect solution - it says I can't upvote yet, so I will wait 11 minutes and set as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @JackRolph Glad to help. See my edit for a bit more explanation.

Comment: One other way you could do it is to use two capture groups: `:%s/\v(RESULT\=)(.*)/\1200`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Good point! But in fact a single group will suffice: %s/\v(RESULT\=).*/\1200

Answer (score 3):

@Rich's solution is a perfect general solution, however maybe your question is a good example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754). For your specific use case Vim has [`:h CTRL-A`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#CTRL-A) and [`:h CTRL-X`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#CTRL-X):

```
CTRL-A          Add [count] to the number or alphabetic character at
            or after the cursor.

CTRL-X          Subtract [count] from the number or alphabetic
            character at or after the cursor.
```

So in your case you can simply put the cursor anywhere between the beginning of the line and the `1` and in normal mode use <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>CTRL+a</kbd>

Comment: You could also do this just on the lines with `RESULT=` with a :global :nomal command! `g/RESULT=/execute "normal! 100\<C-A>"`

Comment: Thanks very much for this! However, I am changing a text file in a bash script and therefore the vim code is more useful in this instance. Nonetheless, thank you for the answer - this will be useful in many other circumstances!

Comment: @JackRolph you're welcome :) One last piece of advice: if you are writing a bash script which invokes Vim to do this kind of transformation you most probably want to use [sed(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) instead :)